# How to parse volley networkImageView to another activity

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am parse text and image from RecyclerViewAdapter to ItemSelection. The text to be parsed successfully, But the image cannot be parse from RecyclerViewAdapter to ItemSelection.

Here is my code:

RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
package com.mbm.www.arbiterrchairs;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import java.util.List;

/**
* Created by JUNED on 6/16/2016.
*/
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;

List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter;

ImageLoader imageLoader1;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter, Context context){

super();
this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items, parent, false);

ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Viewholder, int position) {

GetDataAdapter getDataAdapter1 =  getDataAdapter.get(position);

imageLoader1 = ServerImageParseAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

imageLoader1.get(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(),
ImageLoader.getImageListener(
Viewholder.networkImageView,//Server Image
R.mipmap.ic_launcher,//Before loading server image the default showing image.
android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert //Error image if requested image dose not found on server.
)
);

Viewholder.networkImageView.setImageUrl(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(), imageLoader1);

Viewholder.ImageTitleNameView.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImageTitleName());

Viewholder.ImageTitleNameView1.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImageTitleName1());

Viewholder.ImageTitleNameView2.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImageTitleName2());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

return getDataAdapter.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

public TextView ImageTitleNameView;
public TextView ImageTitleNameView1;
public TextView ImageTitleNameView2;
public NetworkImageView networkImageView ;

public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

super(itemView);

itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

ImageTitleNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item) ;

ImageTitleNameView1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item1) ;

ImageTitleNameView2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item2) ;

networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VollyNetworkImageView1) ;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(context,ItemSelection.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("name", ImageTitleNameView.getText().toString());
b.putString("name1", ImageTitleNameView1.getText().toString());
b.putString("name2", ImageTitleNameView2.getText().toString());
//intent.putExtra("nameimage3", (Parcelable) networkImageView);
intent.putExtras(b);
context.startActivity(intent);
}
}
}
```

ItemSelection.java

```
    package com.mbm.www.arbiterrchairs;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ItemSelection extends AppCompatActivity {

int counter;
ImageButton add, sub;
TextView display;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.item_selection);
addListenerOnButton();


counter=0;
add=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cart_plus_img);
sub=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cart_minus_img);
display=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.cart_product_quantity);
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
counter ++;
display.setText(""+ counter);
}
});
sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
counter --;
display.setText(""+ counter);
}
});


Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
TextView product_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_name_value);
TextView product_model_no = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_model_no_value);
TextView product_price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_price_value);
// ImageView product_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_product_image);

product_name.setText(b.getCharSequence("name"));
product_model_no.setText(b.getCharSequence("name1"));
product_price.setText(b.getCharSequence("name2"));
//product_image.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) b.getParcelable("nameimage3"));
}
private void addListenerOnButton() {
final Context context = this;
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_to_cart);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

Intent intent = new Intent(context, Checkout.class);
startActivity(intent);
}

});
}
}
```

Comment: `But the image cannot be parse from RecyclerViewAdapter to ItemSelection` couldn't get your problem.

Comment: The image networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VollyNetworkImageView1) ; cannot be parsed to next activity. how to parse it?

Comment: There is no need to pars the network image on its own, since the bitmap gets cached.

Comment: k sir. how to display this image to next activity?